# import csv error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to import a CSV file that I exported from supabase using PGAdmin I keep getting this error:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
> ? CONTEXT: COPY User, line 2, column emailVerified: ""

In Supabase, the emailVerified field is empty for all records. The CSV example looks like this:

```
"id","name","email","emailVerified","image"    
"abc123","Guy Man","guyt@man.com","","https://pic.com"
```

I tried editing the CSV and added NULL to the emailVerified field but same error. I also tried adding Null to the import options in PGAdmin.

I then tried to manually enter a record. I added the one above by entering each field. I didn't enter anything for emailVerified and it accepted it.

How do I avoid this problem? This was a test table with 5 records in it, I can add these all manually, but this isn't an ideal solution. How do I get PgAdmin to accept the record as it was written in the CSV?

Comment: The error is correct `""` is not a valid timestamp format. If you using `COPY ... WITH CSV` then a `NULL` is an unquoted empty string per [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). Try outputting your CSV without the quoting. Option 2 would be to `COPY` to a staging table that has all its columns as `varchar` and then clean up the data and transfer it to the final table.

Answer (score 1):

The default way to represent NULL in the CSV format is with a completely empty string.  So in your case, that would look like:

> "abc123","Guy Man","guyt@man.com",,"https://pic.com"

Note the lack of double quotes for the 4th field.

To import the data as it currently is, you would specify `force_null ("emailVerified")` to the COPY command. That tells it to look for the NULL-signifying string even if it is within double quotes. But as far as I can tell, there is no way to construct such a COPY command via the pgAdmin4 GUI method.

So you either need to construct the command manually and run it in psql, or edit your input file to omit the double quotes around the null field.